# Ionic4: Binding not working from external devices

Tags: android, angular, ionic4

The application reads a barcode from an external device. The barcode code is correctly displayed on the screen but the form is not bound.

The same binding problem occurs even if an array is modified and displayed in an ion-list.
The problem only occurs on a hardware device (BlackView 5500) while everything works correctly from Google Chrome.

```
export class EsempioPage implements OnInit {
  public barcode="";
  public tmp_barcode = "";

  constructor() { 
    this.barcode="";
  }

  public setBarcode(val:string){
    this.barcode = ""+val;
    console.log("barcode:"+this.barcode);
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  @HostListener('document:keypress', ['$event'])
  handleKeyboardEvent(event: KeyboardEvent) { 

    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
      this.setBarcode(this.tmp_barcode);
      this.tmp_barcode = "";
    }else{
      this.tmp_barcode = this.tmp_barcode  + event.key;
    }
  }

}



<ion-content>
  <p>VALUE: {{barcode}}</p>
  <ion-item>
      <input type="text"
      [value]="barcode"
      (input)="barcode = $event.target.value" />
  </ion-item>
</ion-content>
```

I expect a correct binding

Comment: Fixed invoking ChangeDetectorRef.